# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException in Apache Camel: when is it thrown?

Tags: http, apache-camel

I'm trying to wire up some exception handlers in Apache Camel, and I've got it in mind that `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException` may be a good exception to attempt a few retries for rather than just logging and giving up. I've been led to believe that this is the exception we can expect if an http endpoint is temporarily down / unavailable.

Under what circumstances is `HttpHostConnectException` thrown? How might I simulate this circumstance to verify retry behavior?

Answer (score 0):

the HttpHostConnectException isn't explicitly thrown by Camel, but is just passed back from the HttpClient execute() call (see http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html)

take a look at this Camel unit test for an example of how to handle/reproduce it...

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpNoConnectionRedeliveryTest.java